# How do I get NetBeans to show visual code execution for URL with GET parameters?

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

How do I get NetBeans to show visual code execution for URL with GET parameters?

In NetBeans I am using Xdebug with a remote server. That is working fine.

The problem is Xdebug with NetBeans only works when debugging files that don't contain GET parameters.

Basically if my file is called `index.php`, and I go to `website.com/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-debug` It works.

If I go to `website.com/index.php?test=1&XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-debug` or `website.com/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-debug&test=1` it runs Xdebug, but I can't step through the code visually with NetBeans.

It seems NetBeans doesn't realize that `index.php` with GET parameters and no GET parameters is a the same file, and thus doesn't show me visually as I step through the code with the debug buttons.

How do I fix this?

Using:

- Apache NetBeans 12.6
- PHP 7.2
- Xdebug 2.8.0
- Windows 10

PHP.INI settings for Xdebug (I am using SSH tunnel hence why my IP is 127.0.0.1):

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-debug
xdebug.mode=develop,coverage,debug,gcstats,profile,trace
xdebug.remote_log="xdebug_remote_log.txt"
```

Thanks!

P.S: I can't use VSCode, or PHPStorm as I am using Namecheap shared hosting, so both those tools don't work.

Answer (score 1):

> Apache Netbeans 12.6, PHP 7.2, **Xdebug 2.8.0**, Windows 10

You need to upgrade, Xdebug 2 and PHP 7.2, are [no longer supported](https://xdebug.org/docs/compat).

Your settings also don't make sense, as you mix Xdebug 3 settings (`xdebug.mode`) with Xdebug 2 settings (the others).

---

To get back to your question: using GET/POST parameters to start a debugging session is pretty much deprecated. Instead, you can use a [browser extension](https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug#browser-extensions) to trigger debugging requests, while your IDE listens for incoming debugging requests. Unfortunately, this is not something that Netbeans supports. Please don't use Netbeans for debugging, as it is so far behind other IDEs such as VS Code and PhpStorm.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Any other ideas? Unfortunately, I can't use VSCode or PHPStorm as they don't work with namecheap shared hosting because of missing dependencies, etc. So ridiculous I can't just set this up easy in 2022... Need PHP 7.2 for older github repos, etc.